# Does compressing data before encrypting it violate any web standards to fulfill the "Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate" header in an HTTP request?

Tags: rest, encryption, compression, gzip, web-standards

We have a REST interface that returns encrypted messages. When we receive a request with the `Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate` header, we compress the data. Currently, we compress the data AFTER we encrypt the data, but we noticed that compressing the data BEFORE encrypting it drastically reduces the content length and would increase performance. Does compressing the data before encrypting it violate any web standards?

Comment: You could use TLS for encryption, and http compression for compression. Compress before encrypt sometimes causes some security issues, compress after encrypt plain doesn't work (data won't be smaller than uncompressed)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Accept-Encoding` header is about which `Content-Transfer-Encoding` the client will accept.  You are not *obliged* to compress just because someone says they will accept compressed content in transit, so you are not doing anything wrong if you don't compress after encryption at all.  (Which, if your encryption is worth anything, will not compress at all.)

You can't set a C-T-E and expect the client to decrypt before they decompress, because the C-T-E header says "apply this transformation before you do anything else with the content".

However, compressing before encrypting *without* the C-T-E header is perfectly legal.  Just do that, and don't set a C-T-E or compress after encryption.